# Behaviour of ng-if on angularjs when using ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I ran into an issue with AngularJS that didn't behave the way I thought it would so I wanted some clarification on it.
I have this html:

```html
<div ng-if="boolVar" > something </div>

<pre> {{boolVar}} </pre>
<strong ng-click="boolVar = !boolVar" >Click Me</strong>
```

When I click the text it alters the value of the variable to its opposite, which is shown in the previous pre tag.
But the div above doesn't show.

If I change it to a function, then it works like I would expect it to.

```html
<div ng-if="boolVar" > something </div>

<pre> {{boolVar}} </pre>
<strong ng-click="toggleBoolVar()" >Click Me</strong>
```

My goal with this was to have one less function that only served the purpose of changing a boolean to its opposite value.

Comment: This is interesting... but I would always go with the function-variant to seperate code and markup.

Comment: div is showing on click, maybe you are not giving the whole code here

Comment: @BillP Yeah Bill, I wasn't showing the complete code because it's way bigger than that snipped. But as you pointed out that it was working I went to try it again and I think I know why it didn't work.
I believe it's because it was inside a ng-if directive, which I believe creates a new scope which shadows the parent scope value (correct me if I'm wrong), making it always be false.

Comment: @lupz Turns out I just overlooked the ng-if in parent (which I omitted here).

Comment: @LoyalPotato that is correct, `ng-if` creates a new child scope and leads to unexpected behaviour